# How to symlink Javascript projects repos into a Meteor app

Tags: javascript, repository, meteor

Meteor has a great file loading policy for general development. It automatically loads files from the app directory with some special treatment for `public`, `private`, `client` and `server` directories. (See http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp)

When loading third-party Javascript libraries into a Meteor app, I usually put them in a `<head>` script or directly in the `client/compatibility` directory, which works well for released files.

However, sometimes I need to link a developing version of a project directly from a GitHub repository from a certain branch, when testing patches or pull requests. **I already do this all the time for Meteor smart packages which are picked up transparently.** However, I'm not sure how to do this for general (client-side) Javascript libraries. Moreover, it's the linking in of a repo rather than a listed version that is tricky. Can someone who has had to do this give suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this was briefly described in https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1229.

I found that this can be cleanly implemented as a resident smart package in your app. This approach works well in Meteor 0.6.5 and any future versions until this API changes. First create the following in `package.js`:

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.use(['routepolicy', 'webapp'], 'server');

    api.add_files('client.html', 'client');    
    api.add_files('server.js', 'server');
});
```

and in `server.js`, you declare that you want Meteor to serve up an entire directory (the appropriate part of the repo) as part of the app (in my case, OpenLayers):

```
connect = Npm.require('connect');

RoutePolicy.declare('/lib', 'network');

WebApp.connectHandlers
  .use(connect.bodyParser())
  .use('/lib', connect.static("/home/mao/projects/openlayers/lib"));
```

finally, `client.html` tells your app to load up the code in the right path:

```
<head>
    <script src="/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>    
</head>
```

Assuming the above package was in a directory named `openlayers`, commenting or uncommenting `openlayers` in the `package` file of my app allows me to switch really easily between compiled releases and running from repo for this package.